# How to provide a repair option in deployment project?

Tags: installation

If setup is installed on machine and if I try to install it again on the same machine than it exits installation with the message "Already installed".  In this case, what I want is that if application is already installed then the installer will repair it.

How can we do this?

Comment: What package type are you using? MSI or custom EXE?

Answer (score 1):

If the installation is actually broken (like a file is missing) then when you re-run the installer it should give you the repair option. Otherwise, if it thinks the installation is normal then it will say it's already installed.

I think there's always a repair option in the add/remove program entry. However, that won't work if your install files were in a temp location and are now gone.